# Remove margin in pages?

Tags: macos, pages, formatting

I want to have zero margin in my document, but there is no way I can't move it. Right now I can see that Document Margins have left: 0 in

However, I can see that there is some weird margin applied, but I don't know where it is set. I can not move the blue tip (see image)

Where am I supposed to move that tip to the left? Right now is 'blocked'.

[image]

Here is another picture to show what is going on...

[image]

Comment: If this isn't a duplicate, just edit in your details on pages version number and why the linked question isn't an equivalent to your question and we can re-open this for different answers.

Comment: bmike, that question is not even answered right? I am having the exact same problem that the guy who asked it in there. Even changing that value to 0, the margin is still at 1.9, and I cant change that.

Comment: We don't allow the same question to be re-asked just because an answer is not provided. Let's edit / promote the original question with details from your situation and see if it attracts an answer.

Comment: I did edit the existing answer and it changes the ruler. Please comment to me in the answer there or here if that better answer doesn't help you.

Comment: bmike, thanks for taking the time to edit the answer. I can't figure out what is going on. I have tried doing what the answer says but I can't make it work. I have added a new screenshot.

Comment: Clearly, something new is here, let's open this for a different answer.

Answer (score 9):

There is an additional set of margins in a Pages document.

I exported a document to Pages '09 and opened it with the old version.  In the Layout Inspector, I found the "Layout Margins". The "Left" and "Before" margins were non-zero and the numbers matched the unwanted margins I saw in Pages 5.2.  Here's a sample:

[image: Layout Inspector from Pages '09]

I changed those layout margins to 0, saved the Pages '09 document, and opened it in Pages 5.2.  Hurrah!  The unwanted margins are gone!

If there's a UI control to view or change the Layout Margins in Pages 5.2, I haven't found it.

Update: BigCaseyDog's answer describes the Document Margins, which are available in Pages 5.2 as well as Pages '09.  In Pages '09, the Layout Margins are available **in addition** to the Document Margins.  The Pages 5.2 templates -- at least some of them -- are built with non-zero Layout Margins, but Pages 5.2 doesn't seem to give us a way to change the Layout Margins.

Answer (score 5):

In the most recent version of Pages, you can adjust the margins similarly as previously mentioned, but it's in a slightly different place. Click the Document button in the top left corner of the window, then look under **Document Margins** in the inspector that appears. You should be able to adjust all of those to zero to get rid of the margins (if you want to get rid of the upper and lower margins, you'll have to uncheck the boxes for **Header** and **Footer** right above the **Document Margins** section). Hope that helps.